# Movie Identification: Fugitive robots chased by military robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots

I'm trying to track down a movie I remember from my youth. The movie was live-action, color, and would have been from the late 70's or 80's. The plot centers around two humanoid robots, a "male" and "female", who escape from a robot factory and are on the run from a tank-like military robot who is chasing them. The memories are vague, but here's what I recall:

- The military robot sounds a lot like Robbie the Robot or B-9 from Lost in Space.
- The male robot is designed to look like he's wearing a business suit.
- The female robot is designed to look like she's wearing a dress.
- At some point they end up in a junkyard and build a "baby" robot.
- At some point, the pair is helped by a human couple.
- There are two bumbling guys from the robot factory who are trying to find the robots before the military 'bot destroys them.
- At one point, the robots are hiding out at a cocktail party or some other gathering of people in futuristic clothing. The military robot shows up and wrecks the place.

That's about all I can recall, but I've had no luck finding it through google searches so far. There have been so many other movies with similar concepts, it's a little saturated with false positives.

Comment: Just to verify; [Robbie the Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robby_the_Robot) DID show up on Lost in Space, but was originally from Forbidden Planet (on film, anyway.) Then there was [Robot B-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_B-9), the robot usually associated with Lost in Space.  (Robbie is the big black robot, B-9, silver.  They both have glass dome heads, to a degree, but Robbie's is a large dome covering quite a bit, while B-9 has more of a Bubble on top of a pole.)  I ask because they have different voice actors behind them. (Dick Tufeld for B-9, Marvin Miller for Robbie.)

Comment: @K-H-W - you are correct, sir (I always get those two mixed up). They both have similar voices though, so I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The movie you're looking for is called [Heartbeeps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeeps) starring the late Andy Kaufman. Here's a plot synopsis:

> Val Com 17485 (Andy Kaufman), a robot designed to be a valet with a
>   specialty in lumber commodities, meets Aqua Com 89045 (Bernadette
>   Peters), a hostess companion robot whose primary function is to assist
>   at poolside parties. At a factory awaiting repairs, they fall in love
>   and decide to escape, stealing a van from the company to do so.

**Trailer on YouTube**

Comment: Yeah, that movie was awful! I remember Andy Kaufman went on the Tonight Show or Letterman and apologized for how bad it was.

Comment: Yep, that looks like it! I forgot about the third robot that looks like a guy in a chair. Gonna have to find this and watch it again, awful or not.

Comment: @Monty129 - I know it gets lambasted a lot, and it's far *far* from flawless, but I have a soft spot for this movie :)

Comment: FYI - here is a much better trailer, if you're interested. Gives a better overall sense of the movie than the short "Crimebuster" one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrGBmi3BVfo